# While using aws cdk with appsync, how to add mutation to graphql schema and prevent deployment from failing?

Tags: typescript, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-cdk

When my schema looks like this, aws cdk deploys fine (notice the mutations are commented out):

```
schema {
  query: Query
  # mutation: Mutation
}

type AppUser {
  userId: String
  fullName: String
}

type Query {
  getUser(id: ID!): AppUser
  getUsers: [AppUser]
}

# type Mutation {
#   addUser(id: ID!, newUser: AppUser!): AppUser!
# }
```

But when I uncomment the Mutation portions:

```
schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}

type AppUser {
  userId: String
  fullName: String
}

type Query {
  getUser(id: ID!): AppUser
  getUsers: [AppUser]
}

type Mutation {
  addUser(newUser: AppUser!): AppUser!
}
```

The cdk fails at at the `AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema` with the following message:
*Schema Creation Status is FAILED with details: Internal Failure while saving the schema.* Help?

Answer (score 3):

The error message from aws cdk was quite vague. The issue was with my graphql schema. The type `AppUser` cannot be used as a type for the input of the `addUser` mutation. My solution was to create a new type with an identical data structure as the `AppUser` and start it with `input` instead of `type`. The new schema looks like this:

```
schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}

type AppUser {
  userId: String
  fullName: String
}

input NewUser {
  userId: String
  fullName: String
}

type Query {
  getUser(id: ID!): AppUser
  getUsers: [AppUser]
}

type Mutation {
  addUser(newUser: NewUser!): AppUser!
}
```